# Can I send japanese mail by using skpsmtpmessage?

Tags: iphone, email, smtp

I make application of iphone, and I must send Japanese mail.
So I use skpsmtpmessage.
But mail that application send is garbled e-mail.

Could you tell me the way sending japanese mail?

Comment: Have you checked the encoding?

Comment: Definitely encoding. Should use UTF-8, if you aren't already! I am pretty sure we have Japanese customers on [PostageApp](http://postageapp.com) and because of them, we have to support UTF-8 when we send, and it appears just fine.

Answer (score 0):

what's your nsstring encoding?

```
    SKPSMTPMessage *testMsg = [[SKPSMTPMessage alloc] init];
    testMsg.fromEmail = @"test@gmail.com";
    testMsg.toEmail =@"to@gmail.com";
    testMsg.relayHost = @"smtp.gmail.com";
    testMsg.requiresAuth = YES;
    testMsg.login = @"test@gmail.com";
    testMsg.pass = @"test";
    testMsg.subject = [NSString stringWithCString:"测试" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    testMsg.bccEmail = @"bcc@gmail.com";
    testMsg.wantsSecure = YES; // smtp.gmail.com doesn't work without TLS!

    // Only do this for self-signed certs!
    // testMsg.validateSSLChain = NO;
    testMsg.delegate = self;

    NSDictionary *plainPart = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"text/plain",kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,
                               [NSString stringWithCString:"测试正文" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,@"8bit",kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey,nil];

    NSString *vcfPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"vcf"];
    NSData *vcfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:vcfPath];

    NSDictionary *vcfPart = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"text/directory;\r\n\tx-unix-mode=0644;\r\n\tname=\"test.vcf\"",kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,
                                 @"attachment;\r\n\tfilename=\"test.vcf\"",kSKPSMTPPartContentDispositionKey,[vcfData encodeBase64ForData],kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,@"base64",kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey,nil];

    testMsg.parts = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:plainPart,vcfPart,nil];

    [testMsg send];

enum {
   NSASCIIStringEncoding = 1,
   NSNEXTSTEPStringEncoding = 2,
   NSJapaneseEUCStringEncoding = 3,
   NSUTF8StringEncoding = 4,
   NSISOLatin1StringEncoding = 5,
   NSSymbolStringEncoding = 6,
   NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding = 7,
   NSShiftJISStringEncoding = 8,
   NSISOLatin2StringEncoding = 9,
   NSUnicodeStringEncoding = 10,
   NSWindowsCP1251StringEncoding = 11,
   NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding = 12,
   NSWindowsCP1253StringEncoding = 13,
   NSWindowsCP1254StringEncoding = 14,
   NSWindowsCP1250StringEncoding = 15,
   NSISO2022JPStringEncoding = 21,
   NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding = 30,
   NSUTF16StringEncoding = NSUnicodeStringEncoding,
   NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding = 0x90000100,
   NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding = 0x94000100,
   NSUTF32StringEncoding = 0x8c000100,
   NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding = 0x98000100,
   NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding = 0x9c000100,
   NSProprietaryStringEncoding = 65536
};
```

Maybe you can try NSISO2022JPStringEncoding